# How to store login details throughout session in ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, windows-authentication

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Application with Windows Authentication. I looked at various options to keep the logged in users data like userid, lang id, role, navigation menu details etc and found it can be done through Session, ViewData, TempData etc. I also thought of putting these details as a class and add to each and viewmodel to persist the data. Do I have to validate all these details by db queries every time to ensure security or using an encrypted cookie is good enough? Could you please suggest the best solution to adopt?

I tried using session and default timeout is 20 minutes. Also I am not sure whether I can use session in a windows-authentication application.

Comment: IMHO, start with the core question of asking yourself _why_ you'd do Windows Authentication. Unless it's an intranet, or a public site with a few users, _managing **Windows User** accounts (AD, machine, etc) goes with it_

Comment: I am developing an intranet application.. no access to external users required.